# How to link guest and user checkout together?

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and I'm confused with the checkout. I have the "accounts" app for the user to enter their profile and I want to link it with the checkout but also include guest checkout. Right now I'm good to the guest-checkout but I cant link the user info from "accounts" app to the checkout.

The is the error I am getting:

> IntegrityError at /usercheckout/
>   NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id "

accounts/models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(default='none@email.com')
    birth_date = models.DateField(default='1999-12-31')
    address = models.TextField(default='')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

orders/models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created', )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    orderu = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product_info, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

orders/views.py

```
def guestcheckout(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear()
        return render(request, 'order/created.html', {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'order/create.html', {'form': form,"cart":cart})

def choose_checkout(request):
    return render(request,'order/chooserequest.html',)

@login_required
def usercheckout(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    orderu=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear()
       return render(request, 'order/created.html',{'order': order})
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'order/usercheckoutnormal.html', {'form': form,"cart":cart})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are including the ProfileForm on the checkout page. The error happens because it is trying to create a new profile each time, but each user can only have a single profile.

Comment: I want to include guest checkout so that the non-user could also purchase products

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. Why did you include a ProfileForm on the page? That has nothing to do with checkouts, it's for creating or editing a profile.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `OneToOneField` of `user` is null. Set a user before saving the form, let say -

```
@login_required
def usercheckout(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    user = request.user
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProfileForm(request.POST,instance=profile)
       if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    orderu=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear()
       return render(request, 'order/created.html',{'order': order})
    else:   
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'order/usercheckoutnormal.html', {'form': form,"cart":cart})
```

Comment: it says "UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id"

Comment: error is clear itself, it's because of you already have a `Profile` object with this user, pass instance in form I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm very appreciated

Comment: it then says "IntegrityError at /usercheckout/
NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_orderitem.order_id"

Comment: @PhasinOpaspilai you have to understand the errors in coding, error is clear - your `OrderItem` model does not have any `order `, create a `Order`  object first and then pass it into like `OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=new_order,..` and I completely agreed with Daniel creating ProfileForm has nothing to do with checkouts